# Trying to understand C++ deep copy

Tags: c++, deep-copy

I Know how to write the code , but can't explain the meaning of the code here:

```
 ArrayList& ArrayList::operator =(const ArrayList& other) {
          delete[] m_elements;
          copy(other);
          return *this; 
 }
```

**1st Question**

I know `ArrayList&` means "pass it by reference". But this is the first time for me to see `ArrayList&` as return type of a method. What is the difference between:

```
ArrayList ArrayList :: operator() {}
```

and

```
ArrayList& ArrayList :: operator(){}
```

**2nd Question**

Whats does `return  *this` mean? Why return the pointer? Shouldn't it be `return this;`?

**** EDITED

**3rd QUestion**

Does the code below mean "This method Return some strange memory address (something like  0x90183930)" by Reference" ?

```
             ArrayList*& ArrayList ::operator(){}
```

Comment: if you cant follow this, you shoudl start with a simpler operator=, thus you wouldnt be distracted by the bug (on line 2).

Comment: See this for example: `int get1X() { return x; }` and `int& get2X() { return x; }`..testing it. First: `get1X() = 0` <- error! Second: `get2X() = 0` <-compiles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard assignment operator semantics return the assigned value as a result of the assignment.

So really it should return either an ArrayList or a const ArrayList&. The later is preferred with large objects, since it only passes around an address, not a full copy of the value in question.

btw, its returning *this, since after having completed the assignment, *this is the value that was assigned.

Comment: Why should the returned reference be `const`? Why not allow something like `(array1 = array2) += array3`? If you're returning self for chaining purposes, might as well allow it well.

Comment: hmm, not sure I can agree entirely with you there, but I might be working from a style guide with this thought, and I can almost see that being a useful thing.

Answer (score 2):

A datatype followed by an ampersand in C++ is simply a reference to the object, instead of the object as a whole (which would be a copy). Hence `ArrayList&` is a reference to an object of type `ArrayList`.

The second question follows from this. In the context of class `ArrayList`, `this` is a pointer to the current instance, thus of type `ArrayList*`. The `*` before `this` dereferences this pointer, resulting in the object being pointed to, which is valid to be passed by reference, and as such conforms to the specified return type of `ArrayList&`.

If it returned `this` instead of `*this` the return type would've had to be `ArrayList*`.

Comment: So if the code changed to  [ ArrayList* ]  with   [ return this;]    the result would be "return some strange Einstien's 16bit address 0x0817393849494849404 " right ??

Comment: That's not 16 bits, but apart from that yeah.